# Common scale based on two different series

Tags: algorithm, math

The following is bothering me for some time:

I have two series of numbers, one representing video timestamps, the other one representing audio timestamps. These two are using different scales, the video is in nanoseconds, the audio is in microseconds, (or the other way around, or micro seconds and nanoseconds, or anything else, the important thing is that they are NOT the same ever because they come from two different hardware devices all the time). Now, I want to create a video stream from these two and obviously one of them is always off. Till now I have hacked the solution that I always use the "bigger" one as the main, but this has caused issues with the other stream, in form of audio glitches, or frozen pictures.

Now, I need make a working solution, ie. to create a common timestamps base from these two series. Can you help me with this?

As an example, I get data similar to this:

```
VIDEO: 100 150 200 250

AUDIO: 1000 1500 2000 3000 5000
```

and I would like the output to be a series like

A(????) V(????) A(????) V(?????) and so on .... where ???? is respecting the difference between the consequent VIDEO and AUDIO timestamps obviously on a different scale.

Thanks,
f.

Comment: ..why not multiply the items in the coarser stream by the ratio between?  If they're microseconds and nanoseconds, for example, multiply the microseconds by 1000 to get both in ns?

Comment: Compute the GCD, or use 2 threads.

Comment: If you're at time `t`, you can find the time for next event by `int((t-start)/interval)*interval+start`. Using the `start` and `interval` of the AUDIO and VIDEO, you can figure out next occurrence of each, and in particular which one will happen earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is pretty scientific (though pretty simple) and not so trivial to implement.

**First thing to note:** you actually have the third time scale - system time.

**Second thing to note:** you cannot directly find video timestamp that corresponds to a given audio timestamp and vice versa **but you can** directly find system time that correspond to just arrived video timestamp or just arrived audio timestamp.

So you (1) find the linear conversion from video timescale to system time and (2) from audio timescale to system time.

Now you can find conversion from video timestamps to audio timestamps or vice versa.

Then you have to choose your reference timescale - either video or audio or system time. You convert timestamps of any timescale to reference timescale as needed.

**NOTE** that each individual audio sample has its own timestamp that should be converted to a new timescale so the output sample rate is not the same as input sample rate. And since your linear conversion will probably be adaptive - output sample rate will be different for the different audio packets. All this means that if your reference timescale is not audio timescale you have to carefully resample each audio packet to a (constant) sample rate of your choice with algorithm of your choice (like linear or something more advanced). Otherwise if you'll assume that sample rate did not change - you'll have gaps and/or overlaps between audio packets (that will lead to a very unpleasant audio artifacts).

The most important subtask of this approach is linear reduction: finding best linear conversion between `x` and `y` given a set of sample points `(x,y)`.

This task is usually defined like this: for a given set of points **(x<sub>n</sub>,y<sub>n</sub>)** find **(k,b)** so that the sum of **(y<sub>n</sub>-(k*x<sub>n</sub>+b))<sup>2</sup>** is minimal (minimum square-differences sum).

The answer is

**k = ( M(x*y) - M(x)*M(y) )/( M(x<sup>2</sup>) - (M(x))<sup>2</sup> ), b = ( M(y)(M(x<sup>2</sup>) - M(x*y)*M(x) )/( M(x<sup>2</sup>) - (M(x))<sup>2</sup> )**

where **M(f)** denotes arithmetic mean of all **f<sub>n</sub>** values.

Practically more points **(x<sub>n</sub>,y<sub>n</sub>)** means more precise linear model. The error depends very significantly on **( M(x<sup>2</sup>) - (M(x))<sup>2</sup> )** value (big value means small error). So you have to apply this formula only when you have enough points - so that **( M(x<sup>2</sup>) - (M(x))<sup>2</sup> )** value becomes greater than some limit value.